# Wordpress tagline when sharing the link

Tags: wordpress

I have recently discovered by sharing on WhatsApp the Website i recently worked on, that the base "Just another Wordpress website" tagline shows even if i removed it from the website through the settings.
Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: could be caching related, have you tried using the [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) ?

Comment: @JasperB ok i tried it and it's the OG:description. How can i edit that?

Comment: Make sure WordPress has not set it again, I had this happen in a instance of a website I build. Also try replacing it with your websites name instead of an empty string. Also when fetching it in the Facebook tool click on the button that says "scrape again"

Comment: i managed to fix by downloading a plug in and set the description there